# Providing custom field in serializer using model data

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

In Problem model I'm storing a list of users who have done it. In Problem serializer when user will request his data I want to show him if he has done certain problem. So I created custom field in serializer class and want to fill it using models data.

this is what I have done.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from dsa.models import Problem

class ProblemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    isDoneByUser = serializers.BooleanField(default=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Problem
        fields = ['id', 'topic', 'title', 'link', 'isDoneByUser']

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        user = self.request.user
        userlist = serializer.data.get('isDone')
        print(userlist)

        if user in userlist:
            self.isDoneByUser = True
```

here is the model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Problem(models.Model):
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    link = models.URLField()
    isDone = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['topic']
```

But this always setting isDoneByUser = False(default value)

please help!

Comment: Can you please paste your model here and explain bit more about the problem.

Comment: please post your queries too how you extracted data

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set isDoneByUser to True as it does not exist in your model.

You can however get the boolean with a `SerializerMethodField`:

```py
class ProblemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    isDoneByUser = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_isDoneByUser(self, instance):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        return instance.isDone.filter(pk=user.pk).exists()

    class Meta:
        model = Problem
        fields = ['id', 'topic', 'title', 'link', 'isDoneByUser']
```

Comment: idk why but above code is throwing some server error citing 'request' as Exception Type: KeyError

Comment: @SanskarJain If you use a GenericAPIView (or a view that inherits from it), the context should be automatically passed to your serializer. If you have this error, it means you probably redefined the `get_serializer_context()` or `create()` method. Can you share your entire view so we can help you better?